# Include checkbox in list box

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have created a list box which is multiple selectable as below:

```
<td rowspan="20">
  <html:select property="doneTypeform" tabindex="<%=(i2++).toString() %>" multiple="multiple" size="35">
    <html:option value="">--Please Select--</html:option>
    <html:optionsCollection name="doneTypeCol"/>
  </html:select>
</td>
```

I want to add `checkbox` for each item in the list box. How can I achieve this?

Edit:

Something like this: http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="dropdownchecklist.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#select_id").dropdownchecklist();
            });
        </script>
```

How can I add select_id when I don't have id attribute.I tried with property but its not working

Comment: A checkbox inside every option inside a select? I don't think that's possible

Comment: I tried to add check box inside option http://jsfiddle.net/WzgW8/. It showing check box outside select box.

Comment: Maybe, you are looking for this - http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are referring to is the `html:select` tag, it has a `styleId` attribute that you can use.